# Check Datasource connection during initialization

Tags: java, database, apache, datasource, c3p0

I am using `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` and `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource` APIs to manage datasource connections.
When I have changed the correct connection parameters I was expecting these API gave an exception during initialization but they did not. What am I missing?

```
    <bean id="uslDataSource1" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" lazy-init="false">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="${usl.db.driverClass}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${usl.db.jdbcUrl}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${usl.db.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${usl.db.password}"/>
        <property name="initialSize" value="${usl.db.initialPoolSize}"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1 from dualx"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="false"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1200000"/>
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="5"/>
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true"/>

    </bean> 
    <!-- the DataSource (parameterized for configuration via a PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer) -->
    <bean id="scpcDataSource2" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" lazy-init="false">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${scpc.db.driverClass}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${scpc.db.jdbcUrl}" />
        <property name="user" value="${scpc.db.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${scpc.db.password}" />
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="${scpc.db.initialPoolSize}" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="${scpc.db.minPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${scpc.db.maxPoolSize}" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${scpc.db.acquireIncrement}" />
        <property name="autoCommitOnClose" value="${scpc.db.autoCommitOnClose}" />
        <!-- property name="maxIdleTime" value="${scpc.db.maxIdleTime}" / -->
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="${scpc.db.idleConnectionTestPeriod}" />
        <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="${scpc.db.validationQuery}" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="${scpc.db.maxStatements}" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: did you use "datasource" somewhere?

Comment: yes I am using. I am not having an exception till this related sql command is executed.

Comment: ofcourse not. The moment you try to access it, a bean of datasource is created and voila!

Comment: in seconds idleConnectionTestPeriod preferredTestQuery has to be executed then I am expecting it should gives me an error.